# Issue in using cursor with parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle10g, dbvisualizer

I am using a cursor with both input and output parameters to fetch data from a select query and insert into another table at intervals:-

```
DECLARE

  i_start_date varchar2(20) := '2019-01-02';
  i_end_date varchar2(20):= '2019-01-09';
  v_ack_records record_inst%ROWTYPE;

  CURSOR record_inst(i_start_date varchar2,i_end_date varchar2) IS
  select a.id,b.status
  from table1.a,table2 b
  on a.msg_id=b.msg_id
  and b.t_date>=i_start_date 
  and b.t_date<=i_end_date ;

BEGIN
    OPEN record_inst; 
    LOOP
      FETCH record_inst INTO v_ack_records;
      EXIT WHEN record_inst%NOTFOUND;
      INSERT INTO test_table
        (id,status)
      VALUES(v_ack_records.id,
             v_ack_records.status);

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE record_inst;
    COMMIT; 
END; 
/
```

I am not quite clear on the syntax to use for this.Could you please help on this?
I got the below errors:-

```
[Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: line 5, column 15:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 5, column 15:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 14, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'RECORD_INST'
ORA-06550: line 14, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 16, column 28:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 16, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 22, column 15:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 18, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Start date and end date are inputs and id & status are the outputs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simplified code you wrote; important - for your case - is the `declare` section.

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_emp_rec    record_emp%rowtype;
  3
  4    cursor record_emp is
  5      select empno, ename from emp;
  6  begin
  7    null;
  8  end;
  9  /
  v_emp_rec    record_emp%rowtype;
               *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 16:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
malformed
ORA-06550: line 2, column 16:
PL/SQL: Item ignored


SQL>
```

As you see, the same error you got. Why? Because you first declared a cursor variable - which is based on cursor's definition - but cursor hasn't been declared yet. In other words, should be vice versa: cursor first, variable next:

```
SQL> declare
  2    cursor record_emp is
  3      select empno, ename from emp;
  4
  5    v_emp_rec    record_emp%rowtype;
  6    begin
  7    null;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Apart from that, you don't need to use such a complex code; a simple `insert` does the job. Note the way I declared variables - their datatype is `date` as it probably should be, unless `b.t_date` column's datatype is `varchar2`. If it is, then you have a bigger problem than order in declaration section. Never store dates as strings.

Also, you should switch to explicit joins instead of *oldfashioned* `from` clause where all tables are separated by commas, and where joins are *mixed* with conditions. Your code is somewhat strange as it contains the `on` keyword but without `join` and `where` so ... that won't work.

```
declare
  i_start_date  date := date '2019-01-02';    -- date literal is always YYYY-MM-DD
  i_end_date    date := date '2019-01-09';
begin  
  insert into test_table (id, status)
    select a.id, b.status
    from table1 a join table2 b on a.msg_id = b.msg_id
    where b.t_date between i_start_date and i_end_date;
end;
/
```

---

If you want to use a cursor, consider cursor `FOR` loop as it is much easier to use; Oracle does most of the *dirty* job for you (opening the cursor, fetching from it, paying attention when to exit the loop, closing the cursor):

```
declare
  i_start_date  date := date '2019-01-02';
  i_end_date    date := date '2019-01-09';
begin  
  for cur_r in (select a.id, b.status
                from table1 a join table2 b on a.msg_id = b.msg_id
                where b.t_date between i_start_date and i_end_date
               )
  loop
    insert into test_table (id, status)
      values (cur_r.id, cur_r.status);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

---

If you still want to do it your way, please, do so. The rest of your procedure looks OK (can't test it, I don't have your tables).

Comment: Thank you for the response.It looks simplified and cleared my basic doubts.I have 2 issues in this:- i_start_date and i_end_date both refer to a single column trd_date which is varchar2(20).Can you help on this please?

Comment: As I said: storing dates as strings is wrong. It'll cause problems sooner or later. One option is to apply TO_DATE with appropriate format mask to it. Or, if values are always stored as YYYY-MM-DD, you could try to use them *as they are* because years come first, months next, days last.